# Sql Enterprise vs Sql Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server

Hi I had two queries with respect to Sql Enterprise vs Sql Developer Edition

1) If I create a ssis package using developer edition can I schedule in Sql Jobs in Production which is having Enterprise edition

2)On my research of diff between Sql enterprise and Developer edition I found out that the only difference is we cant use developer edition in Production 
Let's say if both are same if I use developer edition in production what would happen

Comment: For #2: nothing, until you get an audit from the BSA and whacked with a large fine for license infringement.

Answer (score 3):

Developer edition is a full version of the product but is not licensed for use in production - only for development and testing. If you build SSIS packages (or anything) in dev edition you can deploy to a production box - as long as it has SSIS installed.